# do you sit in or at an openspace

Tags: collocations

If I was to write:
*I will be sitting all day on open space*
would that be correct
or should I say
*I will be sitting all day at open space* 
or otherwise. By openspace I mean the typical corporate space where employees sit and work

Comment: You sit *in* the open space. You cannot sit *on* it unless you climb onto the roof, and sitting *at* it would mean you're not actually sitting *in* the space but in some area adjacent to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's not a proper noun, your "open space" likely needs a definite or indefinite article. If the audience of your message understands that there is one specific open space to which you are referring, use the definite article ("the open space"); otherwise, use an indefinite article ("an open space").

As to which preposition to use, you would generally say that you sit *in* a space.

**I will be sitting all day in the open space.**

You would say that you sit *on* a piece of furniture, like a chair or a bench, or you would sit *on* the floor, the ground, or the lawn, as the case may be.

You would sit *at* your desk, or at a landmark, perhaps, or any other place that you are physically next to but not precisely "in" or "on."

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the indefinite article but of course you are right, it should be there